# How do I defeat/sneak past proximity mines?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm at a hallway filled with proximity mines and things are **not** going well.

[image: DANGER, DANGER]

I've tried to crouch past them or in between them but they're very sensitive and I don't think that's a possibility. Shooting them sets them off without me getting killed but it's alarming to the bad guys nearby and that's not good - it is a last resort if I need it. Is there another way to disable or get past these mines without setting them off?

Comment: I passed this section by simply shooting the mines, then getting to cover. The bad guys will come looking, but they won't sound alarm unless they spot you.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's not hard at all if you take these steps. In fact, if you do the following you can't even set them off accidentally (unless you jump or knock something over).

1. Press Caps Lock, or whatever key you've mapped for "Toggle Walk", to switch from fast movement to slow movement.
2. Crouch.
3. Shuffle over to the mine while crouched.
4. Highlight the mine.
5. Press whatever key you've mapped to "activate object". This will
   disable the mine.
6. If you want to take the mine, "activate object" again.

Comment: Finally! The issue here was that "walk" is not an option that the game teaches you.

Comment: Funny how classic staples of FPS games seem to be overlooked nowadays.  I remember back in the day, I had to hold shift to run, none of this auto-running business.

Comment: Using "activate object" again won't do anything but pop an error if your inventory is full.

Comment: @Jeff - To be fair, there are three speeds in this game. Walk, standard (fast walk?) and sprint. And sprint does require you to hit shift.

Comment: Note: if you have a gamepad/controller there is no walk/run toggle, you just have to press the analog stick slightly instead of pressing it fully in the direction you are trying to move

Comment: Here I thought I was being clever by tossing crates at the mines.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find a way to disable mines either.  In that spot, I picked up a barrel and threw it down the hall to safely trigger all the mines.  This will alert a lot of people, however.

Comment: Just like a real spy would do it!

Comment: I too eschewed subtlety, and I applaud you for it, sir.

Comment: Well if you make enough noise (like firing a bullet) you might be able to convince them to come running down the hall and detonate the mines themselves.  :D

Answer (score 2):

I believe EMP grenades will disable them, but you would need quite a few of them to pull it off.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to disabling mines is to walk incredibly slowly (as slowly as possible, then slower).  You'll be able to disable and pick up the mine for placement/selling later.

You could also disable them via explosion (see @Chris and @OrigamiRobot's answers), but that is not preferable for stealth.

Comment: So basically, get in range without setting them off?

Answer (score 1):

I just shot them. It "alarms" people, but they get over it, and it doesn't count as being "detected". I habitually alarm people in order to draw them away from their friends so I can put the beat down on them.

I tried sneaking up on them a couple of times, but it didn't work worth a damn for me...I think partly because I didn't realize there was a mine against the wall I was trying to sneak from. If you're going to sneak through this bit, go all the way to the dead end on the right, and proceed from there. That might work better.

Comment: You can also throw a barrel or other object in front of them, which detonates them without costing ammo.

Answer (score -1):

You can just shoot the mines and hide until alert passes